# Не получается заменить элементы ниже главной диагонали

Tags: массивы, pascal, матрицы, pascalabc.net

Мне нужно заменить элементы ниже главной диагонали в матрице А. Я написал код, но он не совсем правильно работает. Он заменил элементы под диагональю слева, а нужно справо =(

Ввод:

```
Введите число строк 1-й матрицы - A (<=50)--> 3
Введите число столбцов 1-й матрицы - A (<=50)--> 3
Введите 1-ю матрицу (A):
Введите A[1,1] --> 3
Введите A[1,2] --> 6
Введите A[1,3] --> 5
Введите A[2,1] --> 4
Введите A[2,2] --> 8
Введите A[2,3] --> 7
Введите A[3,1] --> 9
Введите A[3,2] --> 5
Введите A[3,3] --> 5
```

Вывод:

```
Матрица А.
3 6 5 
0 8 7 
0 0 5
```

Код:

```
Const Max=50;

Var AA,BB,CC: array [1..Max,1..Max] of Double;
  ii,jj,kk,nn : integer; Summa: double;

begin
  write('Введите число строк 1-й матрицы - A (<=50)--> ');readln(NN);
  write('Введите число столбцов 1-й матрицы - A (<=50)--> ');readln(KK);
  writeln('Введите 1-ю матрицу (A):');
  for ii:=1 to nn do
  for jj:=1 to kk do
    begin
      write('Введите A[',ii,',',jj,'] --> ');
      readln(AA[ii,jj]);
    end;


    writeln();
    writeln('Заменил нулями ниже глайной диагонали < '); {заменить элементы ниже главной диагонали 0, массив А}
    for ii:=1 to nn do begin
    for jj:=1 to kk do
      if ii > jj then 
        AA[ii,jj] := 0;
    end;
    writeln();
    writeln('Матрица А.');
    for ii:=1 to nn do begin
    for jj:=1 to kk do
     write(AA[ii, jj], ' ');
    writeln;
    end;
end.
```

Что мне нужно, если короче
Ну например:
Ввод:

```
3 6 8 4
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6
```

Вывод:

```
3 6 8 4
4 4 4 0
5 5 0 0
6 0 0 0
```

Comment: "Он заменил элементы под диагональю справа, а нужно слева" - ??

Comment: Дополнил вопрос)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ii := 1 to nn do
  for jj := 1 to kk do
    if jj > kk - ii + 1 then
      AA[ii, jj] := 0;
```